# Sharing ms Access front end file with multiple users when back end is sharepoint list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a MS Access 2016 front end linked to sharepoint lists (sharepoint via 365). Works well thanks to all advice from SO.

Previously, when we had the back end as accdb file on shared folder the front end could be updated then copied out to each user (each user had their own copy). Now that the back end is a sharepoint list this does not seem to work.

Is this related to rights to the sharepoint area - I have tried putting it in a sharepoint site that each user has access to (how does it know this). Or does each users front end need to be linked to sharepoint list individually and be  updated individually?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: May not have been clear about what I'm trying to do. Current scenario is 10 users each using own front end linking to one data file stored on a shared folder. When front end is updated each user gets same updated file copied directly onto their pc.

Comment: Now will have back end on sharepoint linked to front end. Can the front end be copied to each of the 10 users after an update without having to relink the sharepoint lists on each file.